# Error al cambiar de fecha

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy haciendo un sistema que se maneja con fechas, pero el problema esta cuando quiero cambiar una fecha, ejemplo: elijo la frecha de hoy y la del dia 14-12-2018, en total son 10 dias lo cual me va a calcular un valor por esos 10 dias, pero cuando quiera cambiar la fecha uno mas dias antes, no me cambiar el valor.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
$tarjeta = 200;
$efectivo = $tarjeta*0.5;
?>

<script>
function data(valor) {
let ingreso = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
let retiro = document.getElementById("retiro").value;
let fechaInicio = new Date(ingreso).getTime();
let fechaFin    = new Date(retiro).getTime();
let diff = fechaFin - fechaInicio; //Diferencia en milisegundos
let dias = diff/(1000*60*60*24); //Diferencia en dias
document.getElementById("totaldias").value = dias;
document.getElementById("valor").value = dias*valor;
document.getElementById("dolares").value = valor*tasa_cambio;
}
```

Formulario

```
<h2>Sistema</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="date" name="ingreso" id="ingreso" autocomplete="off"><br>
<input type="date" name="salida" id="retiro" autocomplete="off"><br>
<input type="radio" id="efectivo" name="pago" value="efectivo" onChange="data(<?php echo $tarjeta;?>)">
<label for="efectivo">Tarjeta 100%</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="tarjeta" name="pago" value="tarjeta" onChange="data(<?php echo $efectivo;?>)">
<label for="tarjeta">Tarjeta 50%</label><br>
<label for="totaldias">Total dias</label>
<input type="text" name="dias" id="totaldias" readonly="readonly"><br>
<label for="valor">A pagar</label>
<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" readonly="readonly">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el valor cambie al momento que cambias la fecha, necesitas colocar el evento onChange dentro de cada input de tipo date, de esta manera cada vez que cambies ya sea la fecha de ingreso o salida, te calculará el valor que necesitas:

```
<input type="date" name="ingreso" id="ingreso" autocomplete="off" onChange="data(<?php echo $tarjeta;?>)"><br>
<input type="date" name="salida" id="retiro" autocomplete="off" onChange="data(<?php echo $tarjeta;?>)"><br>
```

Comment: Gracias David, voy a probarlo

Comment: lo estoy probando y me genera un problema, si bien hace lo que necesito, pero siempre me deja el tipo de al 100% cuando tengo seleccionado al 50%

Comment: Agrega simplemente una condición dentro de tu función para saber si el radioButton está en nulo, si es así que no calcule nada, caso contrario que realice el cálculo según el radio seleccionado.

Comment: mmmm... en java?